# Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: > on <...> which is already presenting (null)

Tags: swift

I am looking for some help here!

I have an ActionController in swift and I am trying to present a UIImagePickerController from one of the actions created, but when I run it, It is showing me this Warning: Attempt to present   on <...> which is already presenting (null), and It is not presenting anything.

Here is my code:

```
    let actionController = TweetbotActionController()



        actionController.addAction(Action("Photo Library", style: .Default , handler: { action in
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.delegate = self

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }))

    actionController.addAction(Action("Take Photo", style: .Default, handler: {action in

        NSLog("Take Photo Pressed")
    }))

    actionController.addSection(Section())
    actionController.addAction(Action("Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler:nil))

    presentViewController(actionController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I tried this: if self.presentedViewController == nil {
                self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }     But it eliminates the warning but doesn't show the pickerController.

Comment: You are presenting ImagePicker before closing ActionController.  Try dismissing 'actionController' and then open ImagePicket in completion handler.

Comment: Do you mean "dismissing the actionController" by using this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ?

Comment: no something like this "         dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
            // open ImagePicker here
        } "

Comment: Got it!!! It works perfectly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is quite self explanatory. You just can't have two view controllers presented at the same time.

You should first close the `AlertController` and then open the new one. For achieving this you have several options, but I believe the easiest is to close the AlertController when you press "Photo Library" and set some kind of *flag* there. This can be a variable named `shouldOpenPicker` that will be always false unless you press the button.

Then you can use the `completion` closure of the `presentViewController` (the one that presented AlertController) to open the picker controller *only* if the flag variable is set to `true`. If it is, you present the picker controller and set the flag to `false` again.

> **UPDATE:**

You should present the second view controller when dismissed the first one, something like this:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo library", style: .Default, handler: { action in
    alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.delegate = self

        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}))
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand the use of the flag, but what is not so clear is how to open the picker controller using the completion closure of the AlertController presentViewController.